# Stream and save tweepy data

Tags: python, tweepy

I am looking to stream and save twitter data based on a hashtag during an event. I don't pay twitter, so I may have restriction limits on my account. Assuming I have a `twitter_credentials.py` with `acc_secret`, `acc_token`, `con_key`, and `con_secret`, and the hashtag `#hashtag`, could someone please help me build this? I'd like it to end up as a json object that I can then convert to pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

The search method allow you to get all tweets refer to a query. I think you will need this function to retrieve all tweets refering to a specific hashtag

You can look on https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.10.0/api.html?highlight=search#API.search to have more details